# Line wrap string

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a string sent back from the github api module that is formatted exactly like this:

```
Added debug mode for developers

Simply add the class DEBUG to the body and you'll notice little boxes
scattered throughout your site attached to each grid item.
```

I'm wondering if there's a css option to clear these lines as the browsers reads the above like this:

```
Added debug mode for developers Simply add the class DEBUG to the body and you'll notice little boxes
scattered throughout your site attached to each grid item.
```

I didn't really want to split the string apart with javacsript but if I have to I guess I will :)

I've tried `word-break:break-word;` however this just splits lines for longer strings with no spaces.
I've also tried `white-space: nowrap;` however this literally just doesn't wrap.

If I console log the data, chrome has two `↵` characters after the word 'developers' which is what is causing the line breaks, are these selectable by javascript?

Any help would be great!

Comment: there's no html, it's a fullstring, formatted with line breaks like the above

Comment: If the string is coming back from an API don't you already have it as a JS string? If so just replace newline characters with `<br>` tags.

Comment: There's no new line characters to replace?

Comment: How can a string be formatted with line breaks without new line characters? (Or does it have carriage returns? Surely one or the other or both?) Maybe you should show the code you're using to get the string form the API and put it on your page.

Comment: @ShannonHochkins It's a bit unclear what you mean by "clear these lines". My answer assumes you mean you want to show the line breaks that are in the string, instead of the browser default of running everything together. Please edit your question to make it a bit clearer what you're really looking for.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your question is a little unclear, but I'm assuming you want to keep the line breaks that are included in the string - rather than the browser default of ignoring them completely.

You'll want one of the `pre` options for the `white-space` property.

```
/* Display text exactly as entered */
white-space: pre;

/* Display as entered, plus extra linebreaks as needed for long lines */
white-space: pre-wrap;

/* Display newlines as entered, plus extra linebreaks as needed for long lines */
white-space: pre-line;
```

Some notes about the differences:

1. `pre` is the equivalent of wrapping the whole thing in a `<pre>` tag.
2. The difference between `pre` and `pre-wrap` is whether extra linebreaks will be added as needed for long lines.
3. The difference between `pre-wrap` and `pre-line` is whether all whitespace is preserved (including spaces), or only newlines.
4. `pre-line` is the equivilant of replacing all newlines with `<br>` tags.

You can see a comparison of the different styles here: http://jsfiddle.net/Gcexh/

---

The other problem you will encounter is that you've got a linebreak between the last 2 lines of your input when you probably don't necessarily want a linebreak there.

You can fix that by dropping any single-newlines, and only keeping around the double-newlines like the ones that separate the first two lines.

This would ideally be done on the server side, but can also be done in javascript like this:
(with thanks to @JanDvorak):

```
text = text.replace(/(\n\s*\n)|\n/g, "$1 ")
```

Comment: While this got me close, it still wrapped text a little weird :/

Comment: What do you mean by "a little weird"?

Comment: http://www.sassygrids.com/-updates, sorry, I should have been more clear, it'son the right hand side and you'll see the same text as above

Comment: @ShannonHochkins use `pre-line` or `pre-wrap` instead of `pre`, and remove line breaks from where you don't want them explicitly.

Comment: If you ask for exact linebreaks, that's what you're going to get, and you need to have enough room to display it. I think `pre-line` would be a better option here, but then the question is why there's a line break between the last two lines - you probably don't really want to say that you need a linebreak there, right?

Comment: @ShannonHochkins You could strip single linebreaks and preserve double linebreaks automatically, like markdown does: `replace(/(\n\s+\n)|\n/, "$1")`

Comment: @JanDvorak I have just edited my answer with what chrome is outputting in the console log, are `↵` characters selectable?

Comment: @jcsanyi It's also breaking after the word 'boxes' when I user `pre-line`, this would have worked perfectly if not :(

Comment: @ShannonHochkins That's because your input text also has a linebreak after boxes - which it's preserving. I suggest you try Jan's suggestion to get rid of single-newlines, and keep only double-newlines.

Comment: @ShannonHochkins see my comment - you could strip single newlines from javascript. Better strip them server-side, however (and wrap each paragraph in a separate element, while you're at it)

Comment: I didn't even see your suggestion @JanDvorak but it worked prefectly, thankyou!

Comment: And thankyou @jcsanyi for this incredibly extension documentation on line wrapping :)

Comment: For completeness, I've copied the code from @JanDvorak into my answer as well.

Comment: Actually @JanDvorak I don't believe that it's replacing the one thatis after the word 'boxes'

Comment: @ShannonHochkins umm.. what? `replace(/(\n\s+\n)|\n/, "$1")` strips all newlines that are not separated from another newline by only whitespace, and `pre-line` adds newlines so that the text displays within its parent.

Comment: This example is using both your `replace` method @JanDvorak and @jcsanyi's help with the `white-space` css. As you can see, the line is still breaking after the word 'boxes', I guess what I'm after is to leave double lines alone, but strip single line breaks. http://jsfiddle.net/u34xp/1/

Comment: @ShannonHochkins hold on... debugging. I forgot a `g`lobal flag but... ah, `\s+` should have been `\s*` I don't want to _require_ other whitespace there

Comment: That did the trick! You may want to update your post @jcsanyi, thankyou both!

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a way to do it with css. The javascript way:

```
var myStr = "Your multiline\n\nstring...";
for (;;)
{
     if (myStr.indexOf("\n") != -1)
          myStr = myStr.replace("\n", " ");
     else
          break;
}
```

Comment: umm... that loop could well be refactored to use a condition in the loop head - which improves readability. Hint: `do ... while`

Comment: This didn't work, if it helps, I have console logged the data and what's making the lines actually break in the string is this: `↵`. Although I don't know what that is?

Comment: I did it just for fast example. Its working. He can refactor it however he wants. This is just the idea.

Comment: @ShannonHochkins That's a newline character. It's an invisible character that makes the string start to a new line - like hitting the enter key.

Comment: So is this character selectable by javascript?

Comment: It depends what you mean by selectable. You can include it in a javascript string with `\n` like this: `"some string\nwith a line break."`

Comment: When I set the string the given value from your post it works. Its makes the string one line. Can you explain whats not working?

Comment: @divoom12 I think he wants the opposite - to make the newlines that are already present to be actually rendered by the browser.

Comment: Well cant you do like this: change the line to this: myStr = myStr.replace("\n", "<br/>");

Comment: @JanDvorak has solved this in a commentabove, thankyou anyway!